# How to flag lines in a file?

Tags: tcl

I have a file test1 :

```
Par1  
Par2  
Par3  
Par4  
Par1  
Par5  
Par5
```

I had made this Tcl to filter it :

```
set thefile [open test1 "r"]
set is_Par1 0
set is_Par3 0
while {![eof $thefile]} {
    set line [gets $thefile]
    if { [regexp {Par1} $line] } {
            set thefile2 [open test2 "w"]
            set is_Par1 1
    }
    if { [regexp {Par3} $line] } {
            set is_Par3 1
            set is_Par1 0
    }
    if { $is_Par1 && !$is_Par3 } {
            puts $thefile2 $line
    }
    if { [regexp {Par4} $line] } {
            set is_Par3 0
            close $thefile2
    }
}
close $thefile
```

Let's assume that the file and the pattern are more complex (i had simplified it)

I have this result :

```
Par1
Par5
Par5
```

But i want to have this result :

```
Par1
Par2
```

I don't see were is my mistake !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to control your while loop with `eof`: http://phaseit.net/claird/comp.lang.tcl/fmm.html#eof

Assuming that you want to start printing at the first Par1 line and stop at Par4 and exclude all Par3 lines:

```
set f_in [open test1 r]
set f_out [open test2 w]
set started false
while {[gets $f_in line] != -1} {
    if {[string first Par1 $line] != -1} {set started true}
    if {!$started} continue
    if {[string first Par3 $line] != -1} continue
    if {[string first Par4 $line] != -1} break
    puts $f_out $line
}
close $f_in
close $f_out
```

Answer (score 2):

You open the output file when you encounter the first `Par1` in the input and then close it when you read the first `Par4`. So far, so good. But then you simply continue reading and reopen the output file when you get to the second `Par1`. That overwrites the output file!

So my guess is you want to stop reading the input after you've found the first `Par4`, right?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code is opening the `test2` file the first time it sees `Par1`, writing some lines, closing it when it sees `Par4`, and then opening it *again* the next time it sees `Par1` in a mode that makes it truncate the file to zero before adding further lines. (The file is closed automatically when your script terminates, of course.)

Either stop processing the lines from `test1` (by `break`ing the outer loop) when you find your first `Par4`, or open in append mode so that at least the first load of interesting lines don't get lost:

```
set thefile2 [open test2 "a"]
```

Comment: I don't want to append, i want just the first part, maybe i should open my file outside the while ?

Comment: @heyhey: Opening the file outside the while will reduce the amount of confusion for sure, and you should `break` from the loop once you've found all the things you want. Keeping going after you've done all the _useful_ work is just wasteful.